# Using the new "manifestmerger" property in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, adt, android-library

In the newest version of ADT (version 20 preview 3), they say that it's possible to make the libraries' manifest file become mergeable with projects that use them:

> Automatic merging of library project manifest files into the including
>   project's manifest. Enable with the manifestmerger.enabled property.

How and where do I use it? I can't see content assist helping with me on this anywhere.

Comment: Also, is there any information about what it merges? I assume activities?

Comment: i think so . i also think all of the rest , like permissions.

Comment: I noticed that it doesn't merge launcher properties of an activity, but all the activities it definitely does.

Comment: odd . maybe you should tell google about it. thank you for telling me ,so that if there are problems, i will know where to look for them.

Comment: You can see the merged manifest in the bin directory. It does merge the launcher properties after all, but somehow it doesn't get compiled in because the app won't launch.

Comment: @Peterdk - yes this is a pain - a bug has been reported for it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41776

Comment: @Mr.Bungle Thank you for pointing it out. I've tried to use this multiple times, sometimes thinking it works, but then it caused a lot of issues...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add the following line to your `project.properties` file of your application project.

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

Introduced with Android `SDK Tools, Revision 20 (June 2012)`:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

> Build System
>       * Added automatic merging of library project manifest files into the including project's manifest.
>         Enable this feature with the `manifestmerger.enabled` property.

Comment: thanks . seems like they've added it lately in their documentation and videos. i've forgot i even asked this question.

Comment: I dude, it doesn't work for me, sadly... I've added this line in my project.properties but since I call `startActivity` in my code, it crashes with `ActivityNotFoundException`... What can I do to prevent that ? Thx in advance mate.

Comment: My bad, I was just adding the `activity` tag in the Libs manifest with no `application` tag... Works great ! thanks a lot !

Comment: google has a video containing this feature : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Erd2k6EKxCQ#t=2939s

Comment: ummmm... i've tested this new feature , and it doesn't import the activities . what's going on ? is there any sample that i can download in order to see if i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running into the Eclipse bug that @Vadimo linked to below? I've shipped a few apps already that use manifest merging and it works as expected for me.

Comment: well i didn't sign the app and i still got this behavior . it just doesn't merge anything.

Comment: Does not work for me as well (debug version). I have ADT20, Eclipse Indigo R2 on a Mac. Probably have to wait until all the details are ironed out. Looking forward for it, though.

Comment: How do you use it on Android Studio?

Comment: @KevinMcMahon After using this line in project.properties, my project R file missing! And i got too many errors on R.something.someID.

Comment: Vdieos are not documentation.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to merge android library project manifest and your current project manifest, you have to add `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in your project.properties file where you referred your library project. But, you should be confirmed some point like ADT version, Also Minimum and target SDK should be same as library project.

Comment: I was facing the problem that R.java was not found anymore, changing the min and target sdk solved it for me. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

FYI:
manifestmerger.enabled=true won't merge the manifest files if you are using eclipse export signed App.
As noted here it seems to be a bug. 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34623

It was a bit of a hassle for me to set up merging correctly as well. (restarting eclipse, open close project..)  To find out if merging is working take a look at the file in ../Your_Main_Project/bin/AndroidManifest.xml. If merging worked you will see the complete result in this file.

**EDIT:** This bug was fixed in ADT v20.0.1 (Juli 2012): http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: really ? so why did they make this feature? i thought that eclipse is the best thing that google support as an IDE . also , even without signing the app (meaning just compile&run from eclipse) , it didn't work for me.

Comment: its not a feature its a bug. It was all running fine for me when I tried to export the signed App.

Comment: you didn't understand me . it's a feature that simply doesn't work for me , not even when running the app unsigned . i don't get it . how could they publish a feature that doesn't work at all ?

Comment: This bug was fixed in ADT 20.0.1 (July 2012): http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 2):

I was facing some errors during manifest merging (R.java file went missing) so alternately I explicitly copied the manifest contents (e.g. I copied just the activity contents)  from the library project manifest and put them in my main project manifest. That resolved the error and everything seems to be working well so far. Let me know if anyone feels this is not a recommended alternative to manifest merging.

Comment: I can confirm that after 3 years into the "bug was fixed" date we are still having problems with the merger. Disabling it and manually merging files resolved the issue on Eclipse. No problems with Android Studio's auto merge so far.