# Issue when using manifestmerger in release mode

Tags: android, android-manifest

In the [last Android SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html), you can merge AndroidManifest from librairies using the manifestmerger.enabled property :

> Build System
>   Added automatic merging of library project manifest files into the including project's manifest. Enable this feature with the manifestmerger.enabled property.

It works great...but only in debug mode ! Indeed, when i release my app in Eclipse using 'right click on projet' > 'Export...' > 'Export Android Application', the generated AndroidManifest.xml contained in apk doesn't contain elements from my library. Any idea ? Do I have to use an Ant script to release my app and make the merging feature working ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Might be worth submitting a bug with specifics. That way they know what to look for.

Comment: Good idea : the issue is reported here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34623

Comment: i've found a workaround : release my app using an Ant script (where the manifestmerger.enabled property is take into account)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest Android SDK and ADT plugin. The problem you mentioned is already solved according to the following post:

[android - using the new “manifestmerger” property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11455240/142239)

They could be found here:

[Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
(Click "DOWNLOAD FOR OTHER PLATFORMS")

[ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)