# A complete list of all Android project.properties options

Tags: android, android-manifest, adt, android-library

I only know the following properties and I would like to have a complete list.

This specifies the target API level (API level 17 in the example):

```
target=android-17
```

This specifies whether the project is a library:

```
android.library=true
```

This specifies the included libraries in the Android way (directories of the library projects are merged into the including project's corresponding directories):

```
android.library.reference.1=../relative/path/to/library/one
android.library.reference.2=../relative/path/to/library/two
...
android.library.reference.n=../relative/path/to/library/n
```

This specifies whether the manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`) of the library projects are merged into the including project's manifest file:

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

I saw the first three in my projects (generated by Eclipse) and found the last one from [SDK Tools - Revisions - SDK Tools, Revision 20 (June 2012)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html), which is very difficult to find.

Would there be a complete list in the official site / documentations / Android source?

**-- EDITED 2013/02/17 --**

Thanks to [android developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/) who reminded me the `proguard.config` property, which is left commented in the default `project.property` file.

This specifies the path to the [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) configuration file:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Two variables are available: `${sdk.dir}` and `${user.home}`. More information could be found in the [ProGuard Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Related Posts:

[android - using the new “manifestmerger” property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976635/)

[Library Project does the manifest file merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457219/)

[Issue when using manifestmerger in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313062/)

Comment: Wouldn't `System.getProperties()` return you a list of all properties?

Comment: @assylias: These are properties defined in the project.properties file, not the Java ones.

Comment: I would also like to know about the available items.  BTW, you forgot this one : "proguard.config=" , which tells ADT where the proguard configuration is , so that when you export the app to be published to the play store , it will (for example) be obfuscated using it.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- Have you figured this out? By now, you should have switched to Android Studio where `project.properties` is no longer used.

Comment: @JaredBurrows : Thanks! I will take a look at *Android Studio*!