# Automatically generate/edit Android manifest

Tags: android

I just wonder if there already is a solutions with annotations, ant scripts or smth. I just find it annoying to manually fill `manifest.xml` file with all necessary fields. I need it because I've got pretty sophisticated architecture with lots of library projects and  ordinary Android projects. Since library project manifest file is pretty much ignored it's difficult to maintain all projects manifests in proper state after each change in one of library projects.

P.S. I use idea, and I know it can automatically change manifest file, but trick doesn't work with library projects.

Comment: This seems very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976635/android-using-the-new-manifestmerger-property