# Is it possible to export library's manifest (permissions, activities)

Tags: android

I have created a library module that is working when I add the permissions and activity tags to every project's manifest that uses it.

I'd like to encapsulate it as much as possible, is there any support for exporting a library's manifest tags so that I, and others can skip this step?

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject alludes to 'no'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the manifestmerger property to true.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10976635/417426).

Comment: It looks like IntelliJ will support this in the next version.  Thanks, this was helpful.